Android immersive mode / kiosk mode with C++Builder
I use Embarcadero C++Builder 11.3 and my Android app should work in kiosk mode or immersive mode: the navigation bar should disappear.
I have found a number of post about this subject but I was not able to get it works for me in any way.
I know C++Builder is not the best IDE to write Android app but someone can help me?
Thanks
